# My notes in Google Contacts are gone since I my new phone synced them

Tags: contacts, gmail

I use the note area in my Gmail contacts to record a lot of information.  I got the new Samsung Galaxy S7 and now the notes are missing.  The Gmail contact app isn't compatible with the new phone.  It has synched across all of my devices and the notes are missing everywhere.  Google blames the Samsung Contacts app.  I did go into Google Contacts and restored to prior to getting the new phone and they are not there either.